# Product of non-Hausdorff spaces

Tags: general-topology

I know that the product of two Hausdorff spaces is Hausdorff. Does it follow that the product of two non-Hausdorff spaces is non-Hausdorff?

Comment: No.  Why would it follow?

Comment: Not from that fact. But is does from $X \times Y$ Hausdorff implies $X$ and $Y$ Hausdorff (provided all spaces are non-empty).

Answer (score 2):

Yes (if you just mean to ask whether it is true that the product of two non-Hausdorff spaces is non-Hausdorff, not whether the statement "The product of two Hausdorff spaces is Hausdorff" implies "The product of two non-Hausdorff spaces is non-Hausdorff" in some nontrivial way):

If $X \times Y$ is Hausdorff and $x_1,x_2 \in X$, take an arbitrary $y \in Y$. Then there would be basic open sets $U_1 \times V_1$ and $U_2 \times V_2$ which are disjoint and such that $(x_i,y) \in U_i \times V_i$. By replacing $V_1$ and $V_2$ with $V = V_1 \cap V_2$, we can see that $$(U_1 \times V) \cap (U_2 \times V) = (U_1 \cap U_2) \times V = \emptyset$$
and hence that $U_1 \cap U_2 = \emptyset$. This would show that $X$ is Hausdorff, a contradiction.

(This of course, depends on $Y$ being nonempty, but the empty space is vacuously Hausdorff. Thus, $Y$, being non-Hausdorff by hypothesis, must be nonempty.)

Comment: The question that was asked is not whether the statement is true, but whether it follows from the product of Hausdorff spaces being Hausdorff.  While any true statement follows from any other statement in a literal logical sense, this does not seem to be what OP meant.

Comment: @EricWofsey I see what you mean, but my interpretation of "does it follow" was "Is this analogous statement true".

Comment: I don't know how you could possibly interpret "follow" to mean that.  Though, I suppose it is possible that OP does not understand what "follow" means in mathematics.

Comment: @EricWofsey And that's your right. I think until there is clarification from the OP, I'll leave this answer up, perhaps with some clarification of my interpretation of the question.

Comment: I did not mean to ask if it follows automatically from just logic. That is my mistake due to ambiguity. I meant to ask if the analogous statement is correct or not. Thank you, Hayden, for a beautiful answer.